# DropZone.js - When instantiating programmatically, the html elements aren't created

Tags: dropzone.js

In the following example, the elements dz-default and its child dz-button (Drop files here to upload) are added to the form -

`<form class="dropzone" action="#"></form>`

When instantiating dropzone programmatically, the elements are not added to the form -

```
<form id="dropzoneForm" action="test"></form>
<script>
    $("#dropzoneForm").dropzone({
        url: "test"
    });
</script>
```

I also tested without jQuery -

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzoneForm", { url: "#"});
```

Why is it not being initialised correctly when using the programmatic approach?

Comment: Maybe you can check my answer in this other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222412/use-dropzone-options-without-form/52597892#52597892 it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: That worked, thanks Danielle

Comment: Your Welcome... If You could upvote it, it Will awesome!!